# How to adjust the column's color in plot bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdJwp.jpg)

Hi, I want each of this plot be one color, for example, the first two columns would be green, second two columns would be red, and ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matplotlib's` bar method with the argument `color`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(4)
money = [1.5e5, 2.5e6, 5.5e6, 2.0e7]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(x[:2], money[:2], color='green')
plt.bar(x[2:4], money[2:4], color='red')
plt.xticks(x, ('Bill', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'Sue'))
plt.show()
```

[image]